RefreshIndicator Not Working with ListView.builder Containing Two Elements
Title: RefreshIndicator Not Working with ListView.builder Containing Two Elements
Question:
I'm experiencing an issue where the RefreshIndicator is not functioning as expected when used with ListView.builder that contains only two elements.
Background:
I haven't been able to find a specific solution to this problem, and I haven't tried any particular approaches yet. I’m reaching out to the Flutter community for assistance.
Request:
If anyone has encountered this issue before and found a solution, I would greatly appreciate your help.
Thank you!

try adding physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(), in ListView.builder. (if it doesn't work i suggest you to share minimal reproducible code to assist you further)
